# can we host wcf service on port 80?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

I need a suggestion regarding the hosting wcf rest service on port 80. I devloped a service and I am hosting this service as windows service on port 80 and this service wouldn't talk to the outside world. The communication is between local browser and service. In windows 7 and later versions I am using `netsh` and in XP I am using `httpcfg` to reserve namepsace on port 80.

If I distribute this to every one would it work on every machine. Is it the correct approch? What are the pros and cons in this approach?

I am suposed to use port 80 only.

Answer (score 1):

Port 80 is used by default to serve HTTP requests, its not part of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol but still... its widely use for that purpose. I would not recommend you to continue with your current aproach since you want to distribute this piece of software, the end-user is likely to find a lot of problems, any software/service running on the machine binded to port 80 would not allow yours to attach.

I would investigate which port its more likely NOT used by any other protocol or if the requirement allows it, make a local scan for any free port and use that.

Comment: I think we can reserve our name space to port 80 right? http://+:80/xxxx so in this case is there any restrications on port 80 namespaces?

Comment: AFAIK, Two or more services can be mapped to the same port, that will not guarantee your service to properly bind. There is no real way to RESERVE a port other than using it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't host anything on a commonly know ports this is a bad idea. Since the service isn't talking to the outside world you can choose a port that isn't in use by another service.

Comment: Here the service resides locally in evryone machine so I am not using IIS. I am using windows service. and here the servie is rest so the the communication is between local broser and servie

Comment: Hey I am using http rest servie not net tcp.I am supposed to talk from broser

Comment: This piece of code doesn't ensure that it will bind to port 7778, if any other service is binded already, it will still fail.

Comment: Tsukasa I need to use port 80 only why because it's free port. I am not planning to use any other ports why because there may be chanses of blocking ports issues in a secured environments

Comment: if the access is only local what would block it? I wouldn't run anything on commonly know ports unless that is the only thing using the port which it likely isn't

Comment: In some secured environmets they won't allow any ports to be opened

Comment: You said "this service wouldn't talk to the outside world" , you don't need the network administrator to open or close ports on the firewall since you are communicating with ur service through the loopback adapter.

Comment: But you are talking about locally hosted which mean it only communicates with itself not the outside world. There for you have no worries about a network firewall.

Comment: Yes i agree with you but I think in some scenarios the peopel may block all free ports for communication so in that case it may fail right? is there any way to completely block all free ports on machine?

Comment: Like I said, when you communicate locally with your service, the windows firewall does not get involved, it can't capture requests made through localhost/127.0.0.1.

Comment: Nothing will be blocked it's local only to that machine